# Routing issue ionic/angular

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, routes, state

Hi I seem to always have this issue with new projects that take me days to get routing working then suddenly it works. I felt might be caching issue but i cannot seem to fix even most simple starter project.

For example ionic starter template works as soon as I change  to new ng-app and create a new app.js file with a new staeprovider it just becomes a white screen? It seems no matter what I do once i change starter to eliteApp for example nothing works.

Any help much appriciated

app.js

```
    angular.module('eliteApp', ['ionic']).run(function ($ionicPlatform) {

    $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
        // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
        // for form inputs)
        if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
        }
        if (window.StatusBar) {
            // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
            StatusBar.styleDefault();
        }
    });
})
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $stateProvider.state('home', {
              url: '/home',
              abstract: true,
              templateUrl: 'app/home/home.html',
              // controller: 'AppCtrl'
          });
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
    });
```

index.html

```
    <html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!--For users deploying their apps to Windows 8.1 or Android Gingerbread, platformOverrided.js
    will inject platform-specific code from the /merges folder -->
    <script src="js/platformOverrides.js"></script>

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/notapp.js"></script>
   <!--<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>-->
  </head>
  <body ng-app="eliteApp">
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any error message in the console?

Comment: if you want abstract state in your app, then you need to define another nested state from that abstract state. if you wish to work this, you just need to remove abstract property from the state.

Comment: Thank You Ameer I will try this and let you know if it works. Prashant there is no error it just doest not route when I cange the path to my new app.js and change my ng-app name to suit

Comment: Ameer you were correct and this fixed the issue. Can you explain what exactly abstract = true is doing?